# Advanced search in windows 7 for only folder names

Tags: windows-7, windows-search, file-filter

My folder structure is like this:

**70-515**\Chapter01\Lesson1-Exercise1-Completed-CS

**70-515**\Chapter01\Lesson1-Exercise1-Completed-VB

I want to search and delete all **VB** folders(including files inside them) inside **70-515** root folder.

But I cannot use Windows 7 search filters correctly, I tried the following searches and none of them worked correctly

"Folder: vb"  ,   "Folder: *vb" ,....

I still have a lot of folders remaining.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try: `foldername:vb` or `kind:folder name:vb`.

Comment: The first option did not work for m. Second option worked just fine (was searching for .svn folders)

Comment: I think `foldername:vb` makes search look inside folders named "VB", where as `kind:folder` tells it to actually search for folders.

Answer (score 2):

I have upgraded to windows 10 and it has a complete search options available in the ribbon like in below snapshots. it is a very nice addition.

1. complete Search Tools tab

[image]

2. different kinds list in refine section

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also if you enable the "natural language search" option you can just type folder foldername to get the same results with what surfasb wrote.