# How to open a directory in Windows 8 using Win+f?

Tags: windows-8, windows-search

When I'd like to open a file called *duck.txt*, I use the following combination of keys.

<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>,<kbd>d</kbd>,<kbd>u</kbd>,<kbd>enter</kbd>

How can I apply the technique to open a directory? Suppose there's a directory called *ducks*. How do I open it?

Today I'm using <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> and browse, which slows me down.

Comment: I can't see why the same technique wouldn't work for directories (it works for me). What happens when you try it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advanced search in windows 7 for only folder names](http://superuser.com/questions/364501/advanced-search-in-windows-7-for-only-folder-names)

Comment: @zdan I get to see the files in the said directory but not the directory itself. Only files are listed, not a single folder.

Comment: @techie007 The question is tagged *windows-8*. There was no screen for file search like that in Win7.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Ok, so what happened when you tried typing `kind:folder du`?

Comment: @techie007 Nothing. I get no matches at all. Already after Win+f and *kind:folder*, there are no hits. We're talking about the big, ugly screen in Win8 you get when you press Win+f, not Win+e, right?

Comment: I knew there was a closer duplicate: [Windows 8 search for folders?](http://superuser.com/questions/493489/windows-8-search-for-folders)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to have a look at [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/).

You can configure it to use and hotkey you like. Here, I've configured it to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>:

[image]

You can then hit the hotkey, start typing out the name of the folder, press <kbd>↓</kbd> and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the folder:

[image]